# In $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$, what is the subgroup generated by 18?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Under addition, what is the subgroup generated by 18?

I know gcd(18.30) is 6 and thus subgroup generated by 18 has 5 elements.

But, under addition, subgroup generated by 18 is something like 18+18=36, 18+18+18=52.?

I just don't totally understand how to find elements in subgroup generated by 18

For instance,

In $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, subgroup generated by 3 has order 4 and and its elements are (0,3,6,9), which is 3+3=6, 3+3+3=9, and subgroup is {0,3,6,9}

but subgroup generated by 8 has order 3 and shouldn't it be {0,8,16} but 16 is not in the $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. My book says that subgroup generated by 8 is {0,4,8}. where did the 4 come from?

Comment: $16 = 4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$.  Think of it like a clock.  Three hours after 11oclock is "2oclock" even though $3+11=14$, we often choose to subtract an integer multiple of $12$ to make it in the range $0,1,\dots,11$.  Similarly for in $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$, it would go 18,18+18, 18+18+18, etc... but 18+18=36 and 36 mod30=36-30 mod30=6 mod30

Comment: Why did you subtract 30 from 36..?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that $\Bbb Z_n$ usually denotes the set of integers $\{0,\ldots, n-1\}$ with the binary operation being addition **modulo** $n$. For instance, in $\Bbb Z_5$, $2+4 = 6 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$. In your example, we have the following elements in the subgroup generated by $8$: $0$ is of course in there by definition, $8$ is in there by definition, $8+8 = 16 \equiv 4 \pmod{12}$ and $8+8+8 = 24\equiv 0 \pmod{12}$. Thus the subgroup generated by $8$ in $\Bbb Z_{12}$ has only three elements: $0$, $4$ and $8$. Can you use this to answer your initial problem?

Comment: For z30, Subgroup generated by 18 has 0 by definition and 18, 6, 22, 12..?

Comment: subgroup generated by 18, I guess, would be {0,6,12,18,22}..?

Comment: I think you meant $24$, but yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you, and it seems like that Zn is a cyclic group with generator 1. is that right.?

Comment: This is true! In fact, any finite cyclic group is isomorphic (basically) $\Bbb Z_n$.